# Command passed as argument to shell script

Tags: unix, shell, scripting

I want to pass a command to a shell script. This command is a grep command. While executing I am getting the following errors, please help:

```
myscript.sh "egrep 'ERROR|FATAL' \*20100428\*.log | grep -v aString"
```

myscript.sh is a simple script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

cd log

$1
```

the errors are:

```
egrep: can't open |
egrep: can't open grep
egrep: can't open -v
egrep: can't open aString
```

Error is because egrap sees |, grep, -v and aString as arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
eval $1
```

Comment: A more correct version would be `eval "$1"`, which takes care of multiple space characters and prevents file globbing.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `sh -c $1` to invoke the first argument as commands in a new shell so that the shell special characters will be expanded.